# mysql "insert into" SQL syntax error problem

Tags: php, mysql

this is the php code:

```
$stringquery = "INSERT INTO sikurim(name, title, desc, category, subcategory)

 VALUES ('$contact', '$heading','$comments', '$catF', '$catS' ) ";

mysql_query($stringquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

And i get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc, category, subcategory) VALUES ('jhjh', ' fffff','fffff',
>   '2', '4' )' at line 1

I can't find what's wrong with the code, can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DESC` is [reserved MySQL keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).  You need to enclose it in backquotes:

```
$stringquery = "INSERT INTO sikurim(name, title, `desc`, category, subcategory) VALUES ('$contact', '$heading','$comments', '$catF', '$catS' )";
```

Comment: Yes, but the best would definitely be to change the column's name.

Comment: and please make sure you apply proper sanitation to your variables if you are interpolating them to your query!

Answer (score 0):

You should escape each value.
Use mysql_escape_string http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php